# SQL Server change tracking cleaner not working manually

Tags: sql, sql-server, change-tracking

I use SQL Server change tracking on a table and disable auto cleanup. I want to delete all records that track manually. I set auto cleanup to disable and set retention time to 1 minute and when I want to cleanup, I use

```
exec sp_flush_CT_internal_table_on_demand @tablename
```

to cleanup and clear all existing track records, but it doesn't clear records and return this:

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
Total rows deleted: 0
Total rows deleted: 0
```

I exec this stored procedure several times after a while, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Does it show any output at all?

Comment: @Charlieface, I add stored procedure outputs to my question

Comment: The [Manual Cleanup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/cleanup-and-troubleshoot-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#manual-cleanup) docs explain you should only pass a table name to `clear any backlogs left by the cleanup thread.`. Have you tried calling the method *without* specifying a table instead? Why did you disable automatic cleanup? Why such an extremely short retention period?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as document said, I disabled auto cleanup to handle cleanup manually and cleanup when I need and set short retention period time because I want to cleanup frequent and rapidly.